# Create dynamic cursor in sybase asa

Tags: cursor, sybase-asa

I need to create a dynamic resultset in a stored procedure in Sybase ASA 9.

Lets say I have a query:

```
'SELECT '+@Description+', '+@Id+' From '+@Table;
```

I need to create a cursor to get all values of that query.
How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR USING @cursorQuery;
Open @cursor
```

And so on.